# Google Analytics V3 - when to use EasyTracker?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm reading GA's V3 implementation guide, and I see that every time an example is shown using EasyTracker, it is warned that it may be null (for example [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/exceptions))

```
// May return null if EasyTracker has not yet been initialized with a
// property ID.
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
```

My questions is: why use EasyTracker? Why not always use:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).getTracker([UA tracking code])
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look a little closer you will notice that the `com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker` only two additional tracking options: `activityStart` and `activityStop`.

So the answer is: EasyTracker is a specialized class which will track Activity start and stop perfectly.

(Note: this is for Version 3. In previous Version `EasyTracker` did not inherit `Tracker` and was therefore a lot less powerful)

Answer (score 0):

in [Behind the Code: The Google Analytics v3 Mobile SDKs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMRAHDdLYWo) says, that in v3 **EasyTracker deprecated**. And we should work with Traker send(), set() and get() methods.

Comment: EasyTracker subclasses Tracker in v3 but still appears to be [fully supported](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration).